# Specific Element positioned correctly in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox...and I can't figure out why?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've been reading up recently on cross-browser compatibility and have learned a lot, but I haven't been able to solve this specific problem.

On a site I built, www.paintnomorect.com, in Chrome and IE the contact form is positioned correctly at the top-left. However in Firefox, it is dropped below the main image, and I don't know whether it's a positioning issue, margin, float, or what...I've tried searching for answers, but most seem to be related to a specific instance and I haven't found one that's helped yet.

Can someone help me figure out what's causing this issue and how to fix it? And is there a good way to troubleshoot issues like this so I can figure out what is causing problems in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to target FireFox only and change a perticular part of the CSS style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This should be red in FF</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float` and `margin-top` and use this CSS:

```
.contentAreaC .jumbotron.has-formbuilder .module-container .formbuilder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This will vertically align the form and keep it all the way to the left.
Also, you can remove the `::before` that you are using to vertically align the form.  I think the `float` was messing things up.